# Getting Connection Reset when lost connection with Smack API

Tags: exception, connection, smack

i implement a small client which runs as bot on my Server.
I test the reconnect method and cut the internet connection.
I always get this error when i establish the connection again:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:205)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:279)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:2992)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1144)
    at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:325)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
```

This is my Jabber-Manager Class:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.*;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence.Type;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JabberSmackApi extends Thread {



    private static final int packetReplyTimeout = 500; // millis

    private String server;

    private ConnectionConfiguration config;
    private XMPPConnection connection;

    private ChatManager chatManager;
    private MessageListener messageListener;
    private String user;

    public JabberSmackApi(String server) {
        this.server = server;
    }
    public static boolean stopValue = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            init();


            performLogin("Test@jabber.de", "password");
            setStatus(true, "Hiiiii!!!!");

            user = "otherUser@jabber.de";
            String name = "otherUser";
            createEntry(user, name);

            sendMessage("Hello mate", user);

            while(stopValue) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopMe() {
        this.stopValue = false;
    }

    public void init() throws XMPPException {

        System.out.println(String.format("Initializing connection to server %1$s", server));

        SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(packetReplyTimeout);

        config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server);
        config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();

        System.out.println("Connected: " + connection.isConnected());

        chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
        messageListener = new MyMessageListener();

    }

    public void performLogin(String username, String password) throws XMPPException {
        if (connection!=null && connection.isConnected()) {
            connection.login(username, password);
        }
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean available, String status) {

        Presence.Type type = available? Type.available: Type.unavailable;
        Presence presence = new Presence(type);

        presence.setStatus(status);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);

    }

    public void destroy() {
        if (connection!=null && connection.isConnected()) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message, String buddyJID) throws XMPPException {
        System.out.println(String.format("Sending mesage '%1$s' to user %2$s", message, buddyJID));
        Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(buddyJID, messageListener);
        chat.sendMessage(message);
    }

    public void createEntry(String user, String name) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(String.format("Creating entry for buddy '%1$s' with name %2$s", user, name));
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        roster.createEntry(user, name, null);
    }

    class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            String from = message.getFrom();
            String body = message.getBody();
            System.out.println(String.format("Received message '%1$s' from %2$s", body, from));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: hi. have you got this sorted out? I am having the same issue :(

Comment: Nope. I kill the application with an cronjob every hour and start it again.

Comment: I am having this problem as well. Unfortunately I do not have control of the servers that this runs on so cannot just setup a cron job.

Comment: Do you used the current API 4.0.6? Maybe they fixed the issue